# Google Chrome will not uninstall

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, uninstall

As it happens, Google Chrome is installed on one of my computers (Windows 10 Home Insider Release Preview) in two instances: beta and Canary. Both instances were linked to one of my google accounts. Today, there was an issue that was coming up on the browser in which if I tried to click on the web page details (where it says secure and has a lock), the menu does not pop up. In addition, if I click the user's name in the upper right hand corner where a profile select menu normally comes up, it also does not pop up. This was the case in both instances of Chrome even after disabling all of the extensions and removing my account from both instances. However, I know that those two should be clickable because in another installation of Chrome with my same account synced on it on another one of my computers with an equivalent version (beta 58.something) and a equivalent version of Windows 10, the menus are able to come up. Therefore, it most likely has to something with the installation of Chrome on this computer.

Thus, I tried to uninstall Google Chrome from this computer. I tried to uninstall the Canary section first, first using Control Panel. No dice. Nothing came up, not even a Windows permission screen for Google Updater etc. Next, I tried to uninstall it from the Settings app, which has been updated with the Creators update in Settings>>Apps>>Apps and Features. This time, a Windows permission screen came up, and a new Chrome canary window icon appeared in the taskbar to the right of all my pinned apps. It was titled "Uninstall Google Chrome" when hovering over it, but the preview and the app itself was blank, meaning that I could see right through to the settings app underneath it. I closed this window using the 'x' that is shown on the edge of the window preview after leaving it alone for 5 minutes and having nothing come up. Running through the same thing (control panel first, then the Win10 settings app) for the beta version, the exact same result happens. Now what should I do to fix the problem?

Comment: What specific build of Windows 10 are you using, and if you fall back to the stable release build, do you have the same problem?

Comment: The OS build is 15063.138. It also appears to be occurring on a machine that I put on the Windows 10 "fast" Insider track, so maybe it has to do with Windows. I will try to replicate the problem again by downgrading.

Comment: 15063.138 is the current 1703 stable release build...

Comment: Well, if that's the case, then there's a problem, because under the windows insider tab of Settings>>Update & Security>>Windows Insider, the setting is clearly on Release Preview, but under the Settings>>System>>About, the OS Build is labeled as 15063.138. In addition, attempts to downgrade have simply sent me to the Settings>>Update & Security>>Recovery page, where there is no "Go back to the previous version of WIndows 10" option that there should be, but only reset options, which I will be unable to use because of data on the PC.

Comment: Release Preview is your license, because you've used the Insider Editions. You just haven't gotten an update lately. Once Creators dropped for Insiders you have to choose to rejoin the Insider updates, which is nice. If you like that version it won't take you off it unless you explicitly choose to do so. But because you're still technically IN the Insider channel, your license is the Release Preview license.

Answer (score 0):

I had a case recently, Chrome was installed to my computer from the official website. It's working fine however it doesn't appeared in the list of programs installed.

No way to uninstall it so I did below:

1. Delete the whole chrome folder under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\".
2. Run REGEDIT and removed Google or Chrome references under CurrentUser\Software\ or LocalMachine\Software

Then I tried to install an older version of Chrome. However computer says:

```
This computer already has a more recent version of Google Chrome. If the software is not working, please uninstall Google Chrome and try again.
```

[image]

But there's no way, also invisible, to uninstall Chrome.

Finally found a solution from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8stY3ty2UJs

Command line does the trick:

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\Desktop\setup.exe -uninstall -multi-install -chrome -system-level
```

It's fully uninstalled and I can install like normal now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use something like [Revo Uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/index.html) which will run the standard Uninstall and then scan your registry and hard drive for remnants:

> Revo Uninstaller Pro helps you to uninstall software and remove
>   unwanted programs easily. Even if you have problems uninstalling and
>   cannot uninstall them from their own uninstaller, with its advanced
>   and fast algorithms, Revo Uninstaller Pro analyzes, scans and removes
>   all remnants after the uninstall of a program. The feature Forced
>   Uninstall is the best solution when you have to remove stubborn
>   programs, partially installed programs, partially uninstalled
>   programs, and programs not listed as installed at all.

2. Just to make sure Revo caught all file & directories, download & install the free [Double Commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/). Run it and hot Alt+F7 (menu Commands/Search). For directory to search, give all of your drives, separated by semicolons, e.g. `c:\;d:\`, and for FileName give `python`. Examine the results (if any, after Revo) & delete as appropriate.
3. Check your path : Control Panel/System/Advanced System Settings/Environment Variables. You probably only need to check the path, which is in System variables, but why not take time to look at them all?

   Path/Edit and it's a teensy little box, so copy/paste it into your favo(u)rite text editor and examine/purge it.

That should be it. I certainly can't think of anything else.

If problems persist, [Nukeit from orbit. It's the only way to be sure](https://i1.wp.com/wp.production.patheos.com/blogs/wwjtd/files/2016/01/140225-nuke-it.jpg).